# is it an Android's call controller capabilitie?

Tags: android, call, key

Let's assume the following scenario:

1. Person A: calls person B.
2. Person B with an Andoid device answers the call.
3. Person A begins to press some keys like "1, 4, 7, 2, 1, 0" from his or her phone or cell phone.

Is there a way on the Android device of Person B to read or recognize what keys were pressed by  Person A during the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android applications have no access to the in-call audio stream, except perhaps if the device is in speakerphone mode and you use the microphone. Even then, it will be up to you to take the raw microphone input and determine which DTMF tones, if any, are being played.